# Batch script for copying and renaming files

Tags: batch-file, batch-rename

I need batch script to copy all files from one directory to another and rename them all to a default name (ex. NAME54.pdf) and continue counting from destination`s maximum number in name.
I wrote some script but it seems not working:

```
@echo on
D:

set count=0
for %%a in (scans1\*.*) do (
set /a count+=1
)

set count1=0
for %%b in (scans\*.*) do (
set /a count1+=1
)

for /l %%c in (1,1,%count1%) do (
set /a count+=1
copy D:\scans\*.* D:\scans\NAME%count%.pdf
)

pause
```

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
SET "destdir=U:\destdir"
SET /a count=0
for %%c in (%sourcedir%\*.*) do (
 CALL :select
 ECHO copy "%%c" "%destdir%\NAME!count!.pdf"
)

GOTO :EOF

:select
SET /a count+=1
IF EXIST "%destdir%\NAME%count%.pdf" GOTO select
GOTO :eof
```

I've set up distinct source and destination directories. You would need to change these names to suit your circumstances.

I've chosen to simply `ECHO` the required `copy` command so that you can see the resultant commands. You'd need to change `ECHO copy` to `copy` to actually execute the commands.

If you append `>nul` to the `copy` command, the `1 file(s) copied` response will be suppressed.

Comment: Thans @Magoo this worked well. I have another issue. Anyway, it would be so helpful if you could make it copy only files that have been created on the date the script is to be ran.